# How to chain noun state in sentences

Tags: pronouns, omissibility

I want to say that key is absent or the value of that key is empty (comes from code)

What is a right way to write this message:

- No key found or **it's** empty.
- No key found or **is** empty.

Comment: @downvoter, please explain

Comment: That’s not really a sentence. It sounds like it’s intended to be a terse error message?

Comment: @Jim yes, its a error message, changed

Comment: How about: "No key is found (or is empty)"? +1 for sincerity. Don

Comment: It’s really two different error conditions.  Someone debugging that code would probably like to know which of those two occurred.  I’d suggest not trying to combine them. ( not the downvoter btw)

Comment: *Key or value not found*. Once you put it that way, it becomes clear that Jim is correct: it's an unhelpful error message.

Comment: @snaggs *downvoter, please explain*. Just our little welcome to low-rep users to tell them how unworthy they are to post here. Don't take it personally. And let me help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to express this in telegraphic style, for concise documentation:

> Key absent or empty